# Mostrar imagenes en dashboard

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Les explico un poco el contexto de el problema. Cree una aplicación en laravel 9 y como funciona mi aplicación: El usuario compra un paquete y al momento de comprarlo se le da la opción para que envié el comprobante de pago mediante un modal. Esa imagen de ese comprobante de pago se debe ver en una vista que tengo para un usuario administrador en donde el puede ver esa imagen que subió el usuario pero no doy como poder hacerlo, ya me funcionaba pero me dejo de funcionar, le comparto como tengo configurado el archivo de
filesystems:

```
 'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => true,
        ],
```

Esto es el metodo que valida y guarda la imagen:

```
public function uploadPaymentProof(Request $request, Service $service)
    {
        // Validaciones
        $request->validate([
            
            'proof' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2048', // Ajusta las validaciones según tus necesidades
        ]);

        

        // Obtiene el archivo
        $proof = $request->file('proof');
        //Codigo ingresado por el usuario
        $code = $request->input('code');
        
      
        // Almacena el archivo en el sistema de archivos público
        $path = $proof->store('public/app/public'); 
       
        // Asignación de campos para crear una nueva solicitud de servicio
    $serviceRequest = new ServiceRequest();
    $serviceRequest->user_id = auth()->id(); // Asigna el ID del usuario actual
    $serviceRequest->service_id = $service->id; // Asigna el ID del servicio
    $serviceRequest->payment_proof_path = $path; // Asigna la ruta del comprobante de pago
    $serviceRequest->code = $code; // Asigna el código ingresado por el usuario
    $serviceRequest->status = 'pendiente'; // Asigna el estado, puede ser 'pendiente' o el valor deseado

    // Guarda la solicitud en la base de datos
    $serviceRequest->save();

 // Redirección a la página de inicio del dashboard o a donde sea necesario
return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with('success', 'Comprobante de pago subido con éxito');  
}
```

y esta es la parte que debería mostrar la imagen:

```
<!-- Muestra la imagen del comprobante de pago en el modal -->
                <img src="{{ Storage::url($request->payment_proof_path) }}" alt="Comprobante de Pago" class="img-fluid">
```

Comment: y el error?? ??